# Query updates the fields of records in database instead of 1 (Codeigniter 4)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Project Name: Houses

My project is to create an application to track information about properties. I have a datatable with an input that allows information to be entered an stored in the database. To view more information about each house, the datatable is clickable using javascript, which takes you to an view houses page. On the view houses page there are a number of tabs that display the information about the houses. One of these tabs allows you to edit the information for the house.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to update the information of a particular column, it updates that column for all of the houses.

Please see the code below

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function edit_houses(){

    helper(['form']);
    $edithouses = new HousesModel();        
    $id = $this->request->getVar('id');
    $data = [
        'p_address1' => $this->request->getVar('p_address1'),
    ];
    $edithouses->update($id, $data);
    return redirect()->back()->withInput(); 
}
```

**MODEL**

```
class ProspectsModel extends Model{
protected $table='prospects';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $allowedFields= ['p_address1',];
}
```

**VIEW**

```
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('ProspectsController/edit_prospects')?>" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
              <div class="card-body rounded-0"> 
                <div class="row p-3">
                  <div class="col-6">
                  <fieldset disabled>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">id</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" name="id" placeholder="id" value="<?= set_value('id', $prospect_details['id']) ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset disabled>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Date Added</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" value="<?= set_value('p_date', $prospect_details['p_date']) ?>">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" name="p_address1" placeholder="No. and Street" value="<?= set_value('p_address1', $prospect_details['p_address1']) ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                  <!--Buttons-->
                  <div class="row mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 float-right rounded-0">Save and Exit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My error was being caused by the disabled fieldset for the ID. Instead if hid it from view and it works.